# Why the two limits are equivalent?

Tags: calculus, limits

I was reading @user164524's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128948/evaluate-lim-x-to-infty-x5x41-6-x5-x41-6?noredirect=1). I wonder why are the two following limits equivalent,

> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{x^5+x^4}-\sqrt[3]{x^5-x^4}}{\sqrt[6]{x^5+x^4}+\sqrt[6]{x^5-x^4}}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{1+x}-\sqrt[3]{1-x}}{x\sqrt[6]{1+x}+x\sqrt[6]{1-x}}$$

It seems we used the substitution $u=\frac1x$ and as $x\to\infty$ , $u\to0$. So after dividing the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[3]{x^5}$ I get,
$$\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+u}-\sqrt[3]{1-u}}{\sqrt[6]{u^5+u^6}+\sqrt[6]{u^5-u^6}}=\lim_{u\to0}\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+u}-\sqrt[3]{1-u}}{|u|\sqrt[6]{\frac1u+1}+|u|\sqrt[6]{\frac1u-1}}$$
But it is different from the limit I mentioned.

Comment: $x\to\infty \implies u\to0^+$ so no need to consider the absolute value of $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limits are *not* equivalent. There are some mistakes in the referred question. Note, the *title* in the referred question
states
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x^\color{blue}{5}+x^\color{blue}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^\color{blue}{5}-x^\color{blue}{4}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)
\end{align*}
whereas the body of the referred question states
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x^\color{blue}{6}+x^\color{blue}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^\color{blue}{6}-x^\color{blue}{5}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)
\end{align*}

Taking the formula from the title we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}&\left(\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt[6]{x^5+x^4}-\sqrt[6]{x^5-x^4}\right)\left(\sqrt[6]{x^5+x^4}+\sqrt[6]{x^5-x^4}\right)}
{\sqrt[6]{x^5+x^4}+\sqrt[6]{x^5-x^4}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^5+x^4}-\sqrt[3]{x^5-x^4}}
{x^{\frac{5}{6}}\left(\sqrt[6]{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\sqrt[6]{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\frac{5}{6}}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{1}{x}}\right)}
{\sqrt[6]{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\sqrt[6]{1-\frac{1}{x}}}\\
\end{align*}

*Hint:* One answer in the referred question mixes up expressions $x^5-x^4$ with $x^6-x^5$ and similar things.

> Here we show
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)=0}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

We recall
\begin{align*}
a^6-b^6&=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5\right)\\
&=(a-b)\sum_{j=0}^5a^{5-j}b^{j}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Letting
\begin{align*}
a&=\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}=x^{\frac{5}{6}}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\\
b&=\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}=x^{\frac{5}{6}}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\\
\end{align*}

> we obtain expanding according to (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}}&\color{blue}{\left(\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)
> \sum_{j=0}^5\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{5-j}{6}}\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{j}{6}}}
> {\sum_{j=0}^5\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{5-j}{6}}\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{j}{6}}}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x^5+x^4\right)-\left(x^5-x^4\right)}
> {\sum_{j=0}^5\left(x^5+x^4\right)^{\frac{5-j}{6}}\left(x^5-x^4\right)^{\frac{j}{6}}}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^4}
> {x^{\frac{25}{6}}\sum_{j=0}^5\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{5-j}{6}}\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{j}{6}}}\\
> &=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2}
> {x^{\frac{1}{6}}\sum_{j=0}^5\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{5-j}{6}}
> \left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{j}{6}}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

---

*Hint:* The following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\left(x^6+x^5\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}-\left(x^6-x^5\right)^{\frac{1}{6}}\right)=\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align*}
Some nice answers can be found *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45970)*.